# Why do we seek real-valued solutions to second-order linear homogeneous ODEs when the characteristic equation has complex roots?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a random question that has been bugging me. In first-year calculus we learned that the second-order linear homogeneous ODE with complex roots $a\pm ib$ to its characteristic equation , has a real-valued general solution of the form: $y(x)=e^{ax}\left(c_1cos(bx)+c_2sin(bx)\right)$. 

To get to this real-valued general solution, some intermediate steps were performed on the original complex-valued general solution, $y(x)=Pe^{(a+ib)x}+Qe^{(a-ib)x}$.
 
 I'm interested in learning why the real-valued case is of particular interest only. Is there a particular reason for doing so?

Comment: We live in the real world?

Comment: Actually, in some cases, the complex case is preferred to the trig case. It's really just a matter of what you are doing. The trig case can be more accessible to first year students and usually makes more physical sense. The complex case can make computations a little easier

Comment: Thanks for the insight, TylerHG. Besides ease of computation, is there any real-world interpretation of a non-real solution?

Comment: André: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is obvious that real-valued solutions would make more sense in the real world that we live in. However, i was just curious: might there be an interpretation for the imaginary solutions? I was hoping someone on stackexchange might be able to offer some insights on that.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor)'s an example of real-world uses of complex exponentials instead of trigonometric functions for analysis of real systems.

Answer (score 2):

If the initial conditions $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are real numbers, then the solution $y(x)$ must be real-valued. And this situation is what you have in most applications.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics, a running plane wave is an example of a solution of [Schrödinger's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_equation), which is necessarily complex. It still remains the solution when you solve [time-independent Schrödinger's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-independent_equation), i.e. when the ODE is real in itself. If you chose the solution as real, you'd instead get a standing wave.

So it's not always true that only real-valued solutions are of interest. Sometimes they are not the answer one looks for.